# glassfish application does not launch

Tags: java, glassfish, jvm, httplistener

My glassfish 3.1.2.2 is up and running but, I don't know what happened, the application does not launch. The browser only gets to a blank white page. I did not make any changes to jvm or any other configurations, checked the listeners, the ports, restarted domain from cmd and also from console, tried to change default port, tried to launch application with default 8181 https port, but still no success. i tried to google my problem but didnt find anything. i also ran netstat -ao, and the server seems to listen on port 80. Everything seems Ok in the configurations, but I still get the blank page when launching the application. Oh, it also happens the same when I try to launch by localhost. Any idea, help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble. I tried to redeploy the app but problem did not disappear. The solution was to undeploy the app and to deploy it again. It solved the problem but I still don't know the cause.

Comment: me too, did the same thing but still can't understand the reason